# How can I get jQuery or Javascript to change css based on the current url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation area in a separate file from my content, and I pull together the two using a php include. I want the navigation area links to change color based on whatever page is active, i.e. the current URL. So I want jQuery or Javascript to read the current URL (actually just the filename, like home.html), then write CSS based on that.

So like, 
if url=home.html, change-css for nav.home.background-> blue

Comment: Just a thought, but is there a reason to do this with javascript over PHP? PHP would offer a browser-consistent solution (e.g. not affected by users who turn off javscript, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your situation, you could try something like this:

```
$("A").each(function () {
    if (this.href == document.URL) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

That checks for every link if the href attribute matches the current documents URL, and if it does add class 'active' to the elements CSS classes.

A small caveat: this will only work if the absolute URL referred to in the menu and used in the actual document match exactly.
So let's say the current URL is `http://example.org/dir/`, then `<a href="index.html">` will not be highlighted, since it resolves to `http://example.org/dir/index.html`. `<a href="/dir/">` will match.
(Making sure the same URL is used for each page throughout the site is good practice anyway, e.g. for search engine optimization and caching proxies)

The different parts used are:

- `$("A")` selects all `A` elements (anchors). You'll probably want to make it a bit more specific by selecting all `A` elements within your menu, e.g. `$("#menu A")`. [jQuery]
- `.each(func)` executes the specified function on each of selected elements. Within that function `this` will refer to the selected element. [jQuery]
- `this.href` returns the [absolute URI of the linked resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-48250443), not, as you might expect, the possibly relative location specified in the HTML. [standard DOM]
- `$(this).addClass(clzName)` is used to add a CSS-class to the specified element. [jQuery]

To make sure `$("A")` finds all elements, execute it after the document is fully loaded (in the `$(document).ready()` jQuery event-handler, or using the `onload` attribute of the `BODY` tag).

Comment: This is amazing, and very elegant. I can't quite get it to work, though (http://i5.nyu.edu/~jpr226/)--what does $("A").each do? Does that require jQuery?

Comment: yes, it requires jQuery. I'll update my answer to explain it a bit more.

Comment: $(this).addClass('active') doesn't seem to work; I tried to see what (this) contained by adding "alert(this)" under that line, and I get an alert that says the current url, which leads me to believe that somehow it isn't doing a good job of selecting the element to be classed

Comment: but strangely enough, $(this).hide('slow') works, so maybe it's a problem with my CSS or something. I'll keep experimenting. Thanks for this, this is awesome and life-changing.

Comment: Can we use window.location.href to get current url in this case?

Answer (score 5):

I think a much better solution would be to set a class on the html tag rather than swap out a css file per page.

```
$("html").addClass(window.location.path.split(".")[0]);
```

and then have any custom css styles based off of that class:

```
html.home > .nav { background-color: blue; }
html.about > .nav { background-color: green; }
html.contact > .nav { background-color: red; }
```

This would only work if each page had an extension to split, that is

---

Since you're using PHP you could do this without jQuery at all:

```
<html class="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
```

or something like that, I know little about PHP but I'm sure it would be something similar or built off of this

Answer (score 2):

```
var url_arr = document.URL.split('/'),
    page    = url_arr[url_arr.length - 1];

switch (page) {
    case 'home.html':
        $('your-element').addClass('your-class');
        break;

    /* other cases here */

}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
    //get the url

if(url.indexOf('home.html') != -1){
    //indeOf returns -1 if item not found in string
    //so if it is not -1 (that is, found)
    //then apply the styles 
    $('#nav').css('background','blue');
}
```

You probably need a switch or case statement, though, to deal with all the URLs/sections.

Something like

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var fileName = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

switch (fileName){
    case 'home.html':
      $('#nav').css('background','blue');
      break;
    case 'about.html':
      $('#nav').css('background','red');
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read the current url in javascript:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

To change a [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) property on a given element:

```
$('some_selector').css({ backgroundColor, 'blue' });
```