# Attempting to change link colors based on url

Tags: jquery

Basically I am attempting to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572767/how-can-i-get-jquery-or-javascript-to-change-css-based-on-the-current-url) but it's not working... 
Could it be because:

1. the url is "index.php?cat=Lifestyles&do=Arrive" and the html of the link is "index.php?cat=Lifestyles&do=Arrive"
2. Or, and this is a long shot, because I'm testing it on a local host (wampserver) and not on an actual "webserver"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the same code that you've linked, my guess is that your document.URL isn't matching as you'd expect.

Debug this line

```
this.href == document.URL
```

In Firefox, this is done easily with:

```
console.log(this.href);
console.log(document.URL);
```

If they don't match, then that's your problem.

**EDIT**

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsDKx/

Testing in Chrome, and Firefox. (Be sure to click "Run" at the top)

Comment: This is so interesting, cause I checked it in all my browsers: FF, Safari for Windows, IE and Chrome (my default,) and it is actually working, in all but Chrome.

Now I'm REALLY scratching my head

Comment: "Should Change" only showed up in red for me in FF, nothing else

Comment: I can't duplicate here. I'm on the latest version of Chrome (on OS X) and everything is working correctly. I'd suggest performing some debugging in JSFiddle to see why it's not working.