# How can I generate with Sphinx a complex documentation website for 3 projets

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I would like to be able to generate an internal documentation website for all our projects using sphinx.

Let's say I have 3 main projects in my company (let's call them *Todo*, *Receipes* and *Calendar* for instance). I would like to build **one** site for all, but to be able to change colors/logo for every sub-projet (*Todo* would be blue, *Receipes* green and *Calendar* pink) so our readers always know what they are reading.

I would like to make one site becauseI want to be able to make search in all 3 projects at once.

The main page of the site would consist of the list of the 3 projets and a search field.

Any idea to do this with sphinx ?

Comment: Sphinx's built-in search searches only the current documentation. You would have to combine the documentation into a single project to use it. You could use custom JavaScript to use the same theme, but change colors for specific selectors based on the filename, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572973/2214933).

Comment: @StevePiercy in your opinion there is no other way to combine in one site 3 sub-sites ?

Comment: I would not say "no way", I just don't know what that way would be. The default search engine in Sphinx is very basic. You could try implementing a custom search engine through https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/websupport/searchadapters.html or https://sphinxext-survey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searchfind.html or other providers.